# How do you insert literal control chars in vim on Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source, vi

How do you insert literal control characters in vi on Mac?

For example what is the Mac equivalent of

Unix ^V^M 
Windows ^Q^M (in vim)

to insert a \r into a substitution string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same like in Unix/Linux:

```
^V^M
```

But, if you want to use the character in a substitution string, then you should write it like it is, `\r`, e.g.

```
:%s/blabla/\r/
```

Comment: Thank you.   The trick for others who are trying to de-Windows their brains, is to use the actual ^ (control) key not the command key that you think is the mac version of the control key (because it usually is) and to use the actual M key for ^M not the Enter key that works equally well in vim on Windows.